# How to get specific fields of JSON objects for which another field is true

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep, json

I want to get a specific info from the below command

```
[root@test opc]# /bin/oci compute instance list-vnics --instance-id ocid1.instance.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.anrg6ljrkfvuezyc6w4ytv75l55nscz7gg7rwzg55twubrza2uz4j7kzu66a
```

The output comes as below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "availability-domain": "ucJX:AP-MUMBAI-1-AD-1",
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaqtzldjhvlvbaoheda67fuwkaldini7h6txiglp7yrx2nc4pm3nka",
      "defined-tags": {
        "Oracle-Tags": {
          "CreatedBy": "oracleidentitycloudservice/abcd7@gmail.com",
          "CreatedOn": "2022-08-23T12:08:39.326Z"
        }
      },
      "display-name": "xx",
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "hostname-label": null,
      "id": "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrdvonadtpflqh2zqd5f4i6nuhppq2pzdvuvr75w4mz6mvy7hdhuia",
      "is-primary": false,
      "lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE",
      "mac-address": "02:00:17:02:F1:53",
      "nsg-ids": [],
      "private-ip": "100.10.10.227",
      "public-ip": null,
      "skip-source-dest-check": false,
      "subnet-id": "ocid1.subnet.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaa2s7zfva3efszqdlacsel7pg2doxcc5yhqt4xt25jrzah5e6ntbq",
      "time-created": "2022-08-23T12:08:41.807000+00:00",
      "vlan-id": null
    },
    {
      "availability-domain": "ucJX:AP-MUMBAI-1-AD-1",
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaqtzldjhvlvbaoheda67fuwkaldini7h6txiglp7yrx2nc4pm3nka",
      "defined-tags": {
        "Oracle-Tags": {
          "CreatedBy": "oracleidentitycloudservice/abcd@gmail.com",
          "CreatedOn": "2022-08-21T16:40:37.685Z"
        }
      },
      "display-name": "test",
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "hostname-label": "test",
      "id": "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljriaxzes5wtacij7lwhcihv72sva3s5od5ngo6i4v6kv4d6zamypza",
      "is-primary": true,
      "lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE",
      "mac-address": "02:00:17:01:DE:74",
      "nsg-ids": [
        "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaadfnpmigo5wnx6ybvjwqziabtzqtgabhsnkbsnv7qjp3euk5jpwva"
      ],
      "private-ip": "100.10.10.214",
      "public-ip": "140.238.162.238",
      "skip-source-dest-check": false,
      "subnet-id": "ocid1.subnet.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaa2s7zfva3efszqdlacsel7pg2doxcc5yhqt4xt25jrzah5e6ntbq",
      "time-created": "2022-08-21T16:40:41.532000+00:00",
      "vlan-id": null
    },
    {
      "availability-domain": "ucJX:AP-MUMBAI-1-AD-1",
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaqtzldjhvlvbaoheda67fuwkaldini7h6txiglp7yrx2nc4pm3nka",
      "defined-tags": {
        "Oracle-Tags": {
          "CreatedBy": "oracleidentitycloudservice/abcd@gmail.com",
          "CreatedOn": "2022-08-23T12:19:59.985Z"
        }
      },
      "display-name": "yy",
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "hostname-label": null,
      "id": "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljrllmihlbt4rlhsag5jr6hewpofg6fzodmkbqnsdjqdmccyvcetpaa",
      "is-primary": false,
      "lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE",
      "mac-address": "02:00:17:01:B1:78",
      "nsg-ids": [],
      "private-ip": "100.10.10.43",
      "public-ip": null,
      "skip-source-dest-check": false,
      "subnet-id": "ocid1.subnet.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.aaaaaaaaa2s7zfva3efszqdlacsel7pg2doxcc5yhqt4xt25jrzah5e6ntbq",
      "time-created": "2022-08-23T12:20:03.295000+00:00",
      "vlan-id": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the specific ids from the section having `"is-primary": true,`
value of

```
id
private-ip
```

In the above case the output should be as

```
100.10.10.214
ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljriaxzes5wtacij7lwhcihv72sva3s5od5ngo6i4v6kv4d6zamypza
```

Can someone please help me in this case. Thanks :)

Comment: man/google `jq` e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jq` is one of several tools that can be used to extract data from JSON objects.

- json¹ output:

```bash
$ jq '.data[] | select(."is-primary") | [.id, ."private-ip"]' file.json
[
  "ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljriaxzes5wtacij7lwhcihv72sva3s5od5ngo6i4v6kv4d6zamypza",
  "100.10.10.214"
]
```

- csv output:

```bash
$ jq -r '.data[] | select(."is-primary") | [.id, ."private-ip"] | @csv' file.json
"ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljriaxzes5wtacij7lwhcihv72sva3s5od5ngo6i4v6kv4d6zamypza","100.10.10.214"
```

- on separate lines:

```bash
$ jq -r '.data[] | select(."is-primary") | [.id, ."private-ip"] | join("\n")' file.json
ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.abrg6ljriaxzes5wtacij7lwhcihv72sva3s5od5ngo6i4v6kv4d6zamypza
100.10.10.214
```

---

<sup>¹ Technically, if there's more than one object for which `is-primary` is true, you'll get the concatenation of json arrays one for each object, you can wrap the whole `jq` expression in `[...]` to get *one* json output consisting of an array of arrays.</sup>